# click on TableViewCell to open profile view of current user

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I am using firebase database and have a table view showing name, age, location, and image of user at index path.row. How would I go about showing another view when the cell is clicked to the users profile with more information and photos of the user. here is the code for my tableView.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return userList.count

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prefCell", for: indexPath) as! SFPTableViewCell

      let user = userList[indexPath.row]

    cell.name.text = userList[indexPath.row].name
    cell.location.text = userList[indexPath.row].location


    if let imageURL = user.image {

        cell.imageOne.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: imageURL)
    }       
          return cell
}

    }
```

[image]

Comment: add tableview delegate "didSelectRowAtIndexPath"

Answer (score 0):

Just used `UITableViewDelegate` method `"didSelectRowAtIndexPath"` and send image to other view controller with its indexPath

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let detailVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImageVC") as! DetailViewController
        detailVC.strImage  = self.arrImage[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
    }
```

In `DetailViewController` take one variable

```
var strImage : String = ""
```

and assgin this variable to UIImagView

```
 imgView.image = UIImage(named: strImage)
```

Comment: Are you fetching image from WebService?

Answer (score 0):

Using Code use didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

or

Using Storyboard:

step 1: select tableview cell.

[image: select cell]

step 2: Control + click mouse and drag in destination view.

[image: drag into anthor view]

step 3: Give Any of segue.

[image: segue]

step 4: Done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this below code

```
override  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtindexPath: IndexPath){

   let detailVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyDetailVC") as MyDetailVC // get the obect of other VC
   detailVC.myImage = <your_image> // assign your image which you wanted to send to other VC.
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC,animated: true // Push to other VC
}
```

in `MyDetailVC.swift`

```
var myImage : UIImage? // Create variable of image type in required VC where you wanted to send data
```

Now use your Image in `MyDetailVC.swift`.

Any further query you can ask.

Comment: may i email you about a query I have with this please